# Do the rules that apply to a lava block apply to the run off from the lava block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering if the rules that apply to lava blocks (they can catch things on fire from blocks away and can travel through one block) apply to the lava that is not on/in the block of lava.

Comment: @ChargingPun It seems to be...except that the answers given do not address lava flow.  They're quite through about the effects it does have, but not about whether or not lava flow acts the same way.

Comment: @Zibbobz, ReallyGoodPie's answer indicates: *Also, flowing lava is exactly the same as source lava when it comes to producing fires.* in the last line.

Comment: @ChargingPun we don't close based on answers.  It's as simple as that.

Comment: @MBraedley, [yes](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/what-happens-if-your-question-is-flagged-as-a-duplicate-and-the-question-isnt-a), [we](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/951/should-different-questions-that-yield-similar-duplicate-answers-be-closed?rq=1) [do](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/what-are-new-users-supposed-to-do-when-their-question-has-already-been-asked-but)?

Comment: @Ender what I meant was just because questions have the same answers doesn't make them dupes.  They have to be the same actual question.  This isn't.  All three of those metas support this.

Comment: @MBraedley, It may not be the same question, but it's already been answered. What happens from here is for someone other than me to decide.

Comment: While I still disagree that this is a duplicate, I do see now that the answer is included in that post by ReallyGoodPie, at the bottom, in the very last sentence, almost as a footnote but it IS there.  And I suppose any answer to this question would (and should) be contained in that question too.  If the asker has any confusion about it though (such as whether flat-flowing or down-flowing lava acts the same too, or whether it chagnes in the Nether), then this question would be prudent to ask for an elaboration on that point.  If not though, then there isn't much more to ask.